# Node.js AJAX route returns data before referenced function is evaluated

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, foursquare

**UPDATE**

Got it to work, but I still think there's a problem. I only get the correct return data if I set the setTimeout timer to be really long, like 2000. If I leave it at 200 then the callback function executes with empty data because the API call hasn't been returned yet.

I've updated the code below.

**Setup:**

I'm sending a get value from the front end via AJAX (jQuery) and then using that value to call the Foursqaure API to get a list of relevant venues back.

This is working "fine" except that the order of events get screwy. When I insert the GET value into the parameters for the function to evaluate, I'm getting a return value that I'm **not** asking for, which then causes the template to render on the front end before the other return value from my function – the one I want – is given.

And actually I don't think it's actually being returned. Just logged to the console.

**Question:**

How can I return the filtered list of JSON objects at the end of the initGetVenues function in places.js via AJAX to the front end?

**Context:**

I'm using this package to connect to Foursquare: 
https://npmjs.org/package/foursquarevenues

## AJAX call on front end

```
    $("#search-items").submit(function() {
        var placeQuery = $("#search-input").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/return/places/',
            data: {"passPlaceQuery": placeQuery},
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#search-results-list").html(data);
            },
        });

        return false;
    });
```

## index.js [UPDATED]

```
returnPlaces: function(req, res) {
  if (req.headers['x-requested-with'] === 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    console.log("I've started routing");

    return places.findVenue({
      ll: "38.214986,-85.637054",
      radius: 32186,
      query: req.query.passPlaceQuery,
      intent: "browse",
      categoryId: "4bf58dd8d48988d1e0931735"
    }, function(err, data) {
      console.log("Venue callback");

      if (err) {
        res.send(500);
      }

      console.log("Attempting render: " + data);
      return res.render("place-results", {
        layout: false,
        foundPlaces: data
      });

    });
  } else {
    return res.redirect("/");
  }
}
```

## places.js [UPDATED]

```
(function() {
  var foursquare, initGetVenues;

  foursquare = (require('foursquarevenues'))('SECRET', 'SECRET');

  module.exports = {
    findVenue: initGetVenues = function(criteria, callback) {
      var jsonUniquePlaces;
      jsonUniquePlaces = [];

      foursquare.getVenues(criteria, function(error, venues) {
        var i, objUniquePlace, range, uniquePlaces, venueName;

        if (!error) {
          range = Object.keys(venues.response.venues).length;
          uniquePlaces = [];
          i = 0;
          while (i < range) {
            venueName = venues.response.venues[i].name;
            if (!(uniquePlaces.indexOf(venueName) > -1)) {
              uniquePlaces.push(venueName);
            }
            i++;
          }
          i = 0;
          while (i < uniquePlaces.length) {
            objUniquePlace = {
              place: uniquePlaces[i]
            };
            jsonUniquePlaces.push(objUniquePlace);
            i++;
          }
          jsonUniquePlaces = JSON.stringify(jsonUniquePlaces);

          return jsonUniquePlaces;
        }
      });

      return setTimeout((function() {
        return callback(null, jsonUniquePlaces);
      }), 200);
    }
  };

}).call(this);
```

When setTimeout is 2000 I get:

```
| I've started routing
| [{"place":"Quills Coffee"},{"place":"Quills Coffe"},{"place":"Quill's Coffee"}]
| Venue callback
| Attempting render: [{"place":"Quills Coffee"},{"place":"Quills Coffe"},{"place":"Quill's Coffee"}]
| GET /return/places/?passPlaceQuery=quills 200 2009ms - 150
```

When setTimeout is 200 I get:

```
| I've started routing
| Venue callback
| Attempting render: 
| GET /return/places/?passPlaceQuery=quills 200 210ms - 11
| [{"place":"Quills Coffee"},{"place":"Quills Coffe"},{"place":"Quill's Coffee"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just return your value from inside `findVenue`. The call to `foursquare.getVenues` is asynchronous. So when the node engine gets to the function call `foursquare.getVenues(opt, callback)` it simply starts the operation and continues executing any further statements, then  index.js continues executing, then you render a response... Finally some time later, the `foursquare.getVenues` code invokes its callback (presumably when it's done talking to the foursquare API.)

You need to rewrite `places.findVenue` to take a callback argument. When you call `places.findVenue()` you will pass it a function to execute as a callback. *That* is when you're supposed to send the response.

Here is a simplified example that you can hopefully extend:

```
function findVenue(opt, callback){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('Done with foursquare.getVenues, calling back to routing function')
    callback(null, opt);   
    // you passs this callback function to setTimeout. it executes it in 200ms
    // by convention, pass a null error object if successful
  }
  ,200);
};


app.get('/return/places', function(req, res){
  console.log('routing function start');
  findVenue({
    lat:40, 
    lng: 70, 
    query: 'foo'
  }, function(err, data){
    console.log('findVenue callback');
    if(err){ return res.send(500) };
    res.render('template', {foo: data});
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, I appreciate it. I'll work on it tonight and let you know (and accept the answer). Thanks!

Comment: So I got it to work based off your suggestions, but only if I set the setTimeout timer to be really long, like 2000. If I leave it at 200, the callback is executed without the Foursquare data. That means I did it wrong, right? I'll update the question above with the new code.

Comment: Hey I just used `setTimeout` as an example asynchronous function. It is fine to directly call `foursquare.getVenues()` from `findVenues` instead of `setTimeout`. Just follow the same callback pattern, where you place any timing-sensitive code within the callback that you pass in: `foursquare.getVenues(opt, function(err, data){ ... }` call

Comment: As you have it now, there is a chance that foursquare's API will respond within your timing window, setting `jsonUniquePlaces` in time for `return callback(null, jsonUniquePlaces);` to have a non-empty value. Put the `callback(err, jsonUniquePlaces)` code inside the  `getVenues` callback instead of `return jsonUniquePlaces`

Comment: finally, this is one of the links I used to understand asnychronous code design: http://book.mixu.net/ch7.html and this library can be quite useful if you have to chain a bunch of asynchronous operations together: https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the links, great resources. I got it to work per your suggestions. In places.js, 1) I replaced `return jsonUniquePlaces` with `return callback(null, jsonUniquePlaces);` and 2) got rid of `return setTimeout((function() { ... }, 200);` Now it works great (insofar as I can tell). Thanks for all your help!